# facebook login app domain error

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I tried to add a Facebook login button to my site using the code and info on the facebook developers website. I've been looking for an answer and tried solutions with similar links but none of them worked.

But I keep getting an error saying that this link (facebook??) is not included in the app domain:  https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?client_id=575024852707971&domain=&origin=1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2FfTmIQU3LxvB.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df1e8c37a812c6ac%26domain%3D%26origin%3Dfile%253A%252F%252F%252Ff2344fd366a085%26relation%3Dparent&response_type=token%2Csigned_request%2Ccode&sdk=joey

This link is generated by the code of Facebook SDK, I guess.

So I tried adding https://www.facebook.com to my app domain in the app settings but thats not possible either. So I don't know, how to make that button work.

Comment: App domain means the domain name where you are hosting your app. Pass a function name in  `onlogin` that you want to run when user authorizes fb login and handle further process

Comment: "I" is always uppercase on English. [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) are other useful advices for non-English speakers.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.The problem was that facebook api etc. doesn't work on localhost so I had to put it online, changed the domains to the website where I uploaded it and it was working. I first tried to solve it by adding a port to my localhost domain but that didn't work.